# Ways to certify a SaaS for security

Tags: risk-management, certification

Is it common for small companies to get security certificates/compliance from audit agencies for their SaaS to present to customers for their assurance?

If so what are the suggested certifications?

Comment: It really depends on what type of service this is - e.g. if it handles credit cards, you have to be PCI-DSS compliance; if it is anything to do with financial, health, or privacy data, you would need to comply with regulations / laws relevant to that, and likely would want to show some assurance of that. On the other hand, if this is a dating site, or blogging platform, it would be a lot less important.

Answer (score 3):

It's something I've seen but seems to be most common with either larger companies or those serving markets that particularly need/value certifications (e.g. finance, government).

In terms of which ones to look at there's a couple of options that I'm aware of, some of which are geographic in nature.

- ISO27001.  General InfoSec one, but very useful as evidence of security processes for a lot of companies
- SSAE16 (Formerly SAS70).  US focused service organisation certification.  Again some US companies might well look for this
- FIT 1/94 - Bit niche and UK based, only look at it if a customer asks.

The advantage of these certs can be that you can avoid customers who have audit requirements from coming and bothering you a lot (i.e. they can rely on the cert and don't need to prove control levels themselves)

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your customer needs and what areas they need assurance.

ISO 27001 series certifications will address your IS management requirements.

SSAE16/SOC1 is specific to controls which have a material impact on financial reporting.

A [SOC 3](http://www.aicpa.org/InterestAreas/FRC/AssuranceAdvisoryServices/Pages/AICPASOC3Report.aspx) engagement allows you to provide a seal on your website showing that you meet the [WebTrust Criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebTrust#WebTrust.2C_SysTrust_and_SAS_70). You may also benefit by providing a [SOC 2](http://www.aicpa.org/InterestAreas/FRC/AssuranceAdvisoryServices/Pages/AICPASOC2Report.aspx) engagement, which is also more technically focused.

AICPA provides a [comparison of SOC1, SOC2, and SOC3](http://www.aicpa.org/InterestAreas/FRC/AssuranceAdvisoryServices/DownloadableDocuments/Comparision%20of%20SOC%201-3.doc).

Depending on the number of customers you have and their specific requirements, they may send their own people to review or engage a third party accounting/consulting firm to provide [agreed upon procedures](http://pcaobus.org/Standards/Auditing/Pages/AU622.aspx) to have a third party review.